# Anyone help me with segmentation fault

Tags: c, steganography

I am having trouble with my decoder and was wondering if anyone could help me out?

basically, i am trying to build a decoder for my steganography encoder, the encoder places a bit from a message on the LSB of every Byte from in the sound file

the Decoder job is to collect those bits up and create a new message out of them

the code is meant to do the following:

> CODE: SELECT ALL
>
> - Go to message array location.
> - set bitindex to 0 an increment till 7 // (8 bits to a byte)
> - go to sound array location
> - if soundbit is equal add 0 to new byte otherwise add one to end of
>     new byte
> - perform bitshift left once
> - increment bitindex

by using various `printf`'s I can tell you it runs smoothly about 3/4 times before crashing.

Hope that makes sense the actual loops look like this:

```
 {


int mIndex, sIndex, bitIndex, mask;
char *message[9];

mask = 1;
mIndex = 0;


unsigned char *soundFile = LoadWavAudioFile("boomedit.wav");

int soundFileSize = GetSizeOfWavFile();



bitIndex = 0;

    for(mIndex = 0; mIndex < 8; mIndex++)//index for message
    {
        printf("1\n");
        for(sIndex = 0; sIndex < soundFileSize; sIndex++)//index for soundfile
        {
            printf("2\n");
            for(bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < 8;)
            {
                printf("3\n");
                int test;
                if((soundFile[sIndex] & mask) > 0)//is message bit > 0
                {                                   
                    printf("++++++++++++++++\n");
                    *message[mIndex] = (soundFile[sIndex] | 1);//adds a one to message byte
                    *message[mIndex] = *message[mIndex] <<1;    //shift bits 1 placce left
                    printf("*****************\n");

                }
                else
                { //no change the LSB to 0
                    printf("------------------\n");
                    *message[mIndex]= soundFile[sIndex] & 254; //adds a zero at end o
                    *message[mIndex] = *message[mIndex] <<1; //shifts bits 1 place to left
                    printf("******************\n");
                }

                bitIndex++;
            }   
        }
    }

printf("\n hiddden letters:%s\n", *message); //print message    
printf("\nalert 5\n");

}
```

Hope that helps anything will be helpfull.

Comment: Which line segfaults? How are `message` and `soundFile` declared and initialized? (Don't use tabs when posting code, use 4 spaces instead)

Comment: Missing open bracket (`{`) for the sIndex for loop. Is that a typo? You're also.... never using bitIndex?

Comment: I think missing bracket is a typo. It segfaults when it gets to adding the bits to my new message array.

Comment: `for(sIndex = 0; sIndex < soundFileSize; sIndex++)
            int test;`
=> wat?

Comment: the segfault starts around the area when i am assigning bits to my message. i dont understand what is wrong though it looks fine to me

Comment: int test is just a variable i made a while ago trying to fix this bug

Comment: @user1796494 - I "fixed" your typeo, please confirm the code is correct, or edit it if it's not. Please also add in your arrays declarition and initialization or we really can't help.

Comment: okay that what the code actually looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char *message[9];
```

You've made an array of 9 pointers to characters, you don't assign them any value or allocate them any memory. They're uninitialized.

The first thing you do now is deference one of those uninitialized pointers:

```
*message[mIndex] =
```

Thus you crash.

---

Edit:

You can initialize it to all `NULL`s via:

```
char *message[9] = {0};
```

But you still can't use that, not it will just seg fault on deferencing a NULL pointer. You have to assign some memory to these to be useful.. for example you could do:

```
message[0] = malloc(100); // I don't know how much you need for your strings
message[1] = malloc(100); // that's up to you, so I'm just arbitrally picking 100 bytes
message[2] = malloc(100); // here to illustrate the point.
message[3] = malloc(100);
message[4] = malloc(100);
message[5] = malloc(100);
message[6] = malloc(100);
message[7] = malloc(100);
message[8] = malloc(100);
```

Then you'll have to free each of them when you're done. Is this want you wanted? An array of strings?

This line:

```
printf("\n hiddden letters:%s\n", *message); //print message
```

implies to me that you were really after just a single string...

Comment: 2 minutes let me see and ill message back

Comment: I innitialised the array by char *message[9] = {};, but it still crashes

Comment: @Babbleshack - That's be cause they're still not initialized. See my edit.

Comment: my task is to hide a message throughout a sound file then to retrieve the same message, 
could i use a for loop to initialize all the cells of my array?

as you can tell i haven't been doing this long.

Comment: @Babbleshack - of course, just change the incrementing part to your for loop's counter and that's all there is to it.

Comment: okay thanks, what did you mean by i will have to free each cell after i am done, 
from my understanding each cell of message i.e. message[0] will hold 8-bits or a Byte, so i need to collect all 8 bits for each letter of my message and build it up.

Comment: @Babbleshack - Any time you make a call to `some_pointer = malloc(some_number);` you allocated memory dynamically. Before you exit your program you need to make a call to `free(some_pointer)` or else you'll have a memory leak. C does not keep track of your dynamic memory usage for you. Your data residing in the string is of type char, which yes, is 8 bits. `malloc()` and `free()` have nothing to do with the contents of your data, but they're needed when working with dynamic memory (where your data happens to be residing)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you post, `sIndex` will equal `soundFileSize` when you get to your first `if` statement.  It looks from here like you are reading one past the end of your array, `soundFile`.  (Assuming the size of the array is in fact `soundFileSize`)

Comment: Hmm what do you mean its reading past the end of the soundFile. 
Basically i find sound-file size using a function supplied to me by my teacher